# htaccess that will redirect anyone who will visit my folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking for a away to redirect a visitor trying to access my download folder

```
http://domain.com/downloads/
```

- this is the download folder where my files are located.

I want to redirect the visitor to a registration page.

and also if they try to direct download the file

```
http://domain.com/downloads/installer.exe
```

I would like to get redirected to my registration page
http://domain.com/registration/register.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it.

```
RewriteRule ^downloads(.*)$ http://domain.com/registration/register.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: how about redirecting them to the registration page? Thanks

Comment: Hi, it did not show the files on the folder, but it display this error 500 internal server error. and it did not redirect.

Comment: Sorry was missing [R=301,L] from the end